# How to export HTML and CSS code from PSD file using Open Source tools / plugins?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone know convert PSD files to HTML and CSS code via any open source software's, Plugins or Frameworks are available to convert it...?
Kindly assist me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least basic knowledge on using adobe Photoshop.

a. You need to know how to deal with layers so you can extract the website carefully.

b. Use slicing tool. after you carefully slice each part. then you can now press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (all at the same time) then choose save
At the bottom option you can see "Format:" choose html and images then save it on your pc.

Second option is 
you can convert you psd to html by going to this site.
http://psdtoweb.de/index.php

I personally don't recommend you to use these methods because the codes in html is not good. I recommend you is study bootstrap instead.